# About RESTful and Action

Tags: rest, struts2

I don't know how to set correct title.

I would like to do like this:

> **/api/users/{user_id}/ <-> UsersController**

**users** is an action and **{user_id}** is parameter

> **/api/users/{user_id}/list**

**/list** -> *list* is *method*.

But I would like to use **/list** is another action in users action

=> I can use

> **/api/users/{user_id}/list/{list_id}/myMethod**

Can I do it with struts2 restful?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You have two options to achieve this:

- Use REST Plugin http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html
- or one of dedicated Restful ActionMapper http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/restfulactionmapper.html

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it. But I just call execute method, I can't use method index, create, editNew, ... Can you help me?

Comment: Why can not you use index, create, ... methods? You can always redefine methods used for each type of request: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html#RESTPlugin-RESTfulURLMappingLogic

Comment: Hi Lukasz Lenart, please view this question & I hope you can help me. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484179/struts2-restful-mapping-configuration