# Struts2 Restful Mapping configuration

Tags: struts2, action, mapper

I'm new in struts2, I tried to use Restful but I can't config.

I have 2 Controllers:

**UsersController**

```
@Namespace("/api")
public class UsersController extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Object> {
}
```

**ListController**

```
@Namespace("/api/users/{user_id}")
public class ListController extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Object> {
}
```

I would like to create API like this:

> **/api/users/ -> method UsersController.index**
>
> **/api/users/{user_id} -> method UsersController.show**
>
> **/api/users/{users_id}/list -> method ListController.index**
>
> **/api/users/{users_id}/list/{list_id} -> method ListController.show**

I tried config **struts.properties**

```
struts.devMode = true
struts.convention.action.suffix = Controller
struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches = true
struts.convention.default.parent.package = rest-default
struts.convention.package.locators = controller
struts.rest.defaultExtension = json
struts.action.extension = 
struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace = false
struts.mapper.idParameterName = id
struts.patternMatcher = namedVariable
struts.mapper.class = org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.Restful2ActionMapper
struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames = true
```

It doesn't work like what I want.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do you use Struts2 REST plugin? or do you have a jar struts2-rest-plugin.jar on classpath?

Comment: Sure, that's the first I add to lib. And I used struts2-rest-plugin.2.3.15.jar

Comment: If so you cannot mix Restful2ActionMapper (from Struts2 Core) with the Struts2 REST Plugin (which has its own ActionMapper). You must decide to use only one.

Comment: That's mean I have to chagne *.parent.package = rest-default to *.parent.package = rest2-default ??? I don't know where? :D

Comment: No, if you don't want to use the REST plugin, remove struts2-rest-plugin.jar and just follow description from here http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/restfulactionmapper.html#RestfulActionMapper-Restful2ActionMapper

Comment: But I'm not sure if what you want is possible with Struts2 :\